# Android Studio 2.2.3 Code Suggestions

Tags: android

I have started learning android and am using Android Studio 2.2.3.

I have used Visual Studio 2015 and in it when I type the name of a method and then type the opening bracket "(" I am shown a list of all the possible method arguments along with their types.

Also when I hover over a method I am shown the return type and method argument types.Currently in Android Studio if I hover over a method I am not shown anything and if I open a method bracket I am not shown anything.

Is there a way to make Android Studio behave like Visual Studio 2015 for the above mentioned case.

Comment: Inside android studio File -> Settings -> KeyMap you can customize your key shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows:

`Ctrl + Hover` the method too see what the method returns.

`Ctrl + P` to see suggestions inside ().

`Ctrl + Space` after a `.` to see methods.

On Mac:

`Cmd + Hover` the method to see what the method implementation.

`Cmd + P` to see suggestions inside ().

`Ctrl + Space` after a `.`  to see methods.

Comment: Thanks it worked...but is there a way to automate this process so i dont have to keep using these combinations???

Comment: AS -> File -> Settings -> KeyMap